# Android: NORMALIZED_NUMBER not showing emulator number and device number

Tags: android, contactscontract

While I am retrieving contacts from my device using

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER
```

The list does not show emulator number saved in contact list and my own phone number as well.
I tried saving it in different formats (+1-XXX-XXX-XXXX, (XXX)XXX-XXXX, XXXXXXXXXX) under different names, but nothing worked.

Can anybody help me on this?